# Not correct numeric value error using Multilevel B-Spline interpolation with SAGA and QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, saga

This is the generated log:

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Multilevel b-spline interpolation (from raster)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'DATATYPE' : 0, 'EPSILON' : 0.0001, 'GRID' : '/Users/PassifloraTsui/Desktop/study_area/ssTemp.tif', 'LEVEL_MAX' : 11, 'METHOD' : 1, 'TARGET_OUT_GRID' : '/Users/PassifloraTsui/Desktop/study_area/ssTemp_BSpline.sdat', 'TARGET_USER_FITS' : 0, 'TARGET_USER_SIZE' : 30, 'TARGET_USER_XMIN TARGET_USER_XMAX TARGET_USER_YMIN TARGET_USER_YMAX' : '132.20166999999998,145.51116999999996,-21.831979999999955,-9.220450000000007 [EPSG:4326]', 'UPDATE' : False }

grid_spline "Multilevel B-Spline Interpolation (from Grid)" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -GRID "/var/folders/nb/kxpdv6xn68xbmxc5l_8rgbcw0000gn/T/processing_abf242d6ade948aaa3a64539df235165/dbc876f6b3d641d7ac65bc37ae745e79/ssTemp.sgrd" -METHOD 1 -EPSILON 0.0001 -LEVEL_MAX 11.0 -UPDATE false -DATATYPE 0 -TARGET_USER_XMIN 132.20166999999998 -TARGET_USER_XMAX 145.51116999999996 -TARGET_USER_YMIN -21.831979999999955 -TARGET_USER_YMAX -9.220450000000007 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 30.0 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "/Users/PassifloraTsui/Desktop/study_area/ssTemp_BSpline.sdat"
'11.0' is not a correct numeric value for option 'LEVEL_MAX'.
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.1

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/saga/
library name: libgrid_spline
library : Spline Interpolation
tool : Multilevel B-Spline Interpolation (from Grid)
author : O.Conrad (c) 2006
____________________________


Usage: saga_cmd grid_spline 5 [-GRID <str>] [-TARGET_DEFINITION <str>] [-TARGET_USER_SIZE <double>] [-TARGET_USER_XMIN <double>] [-TARGET_USER_XMAX <double>] [-TARGET_USER_YMIN <double>] [-TARGET_USER_YMAX <double>] [-TARGET_USER_FITS <str>] [-TARGET_TEMPLATE <str>] [-TARGET_OUT_GRID <str>] [-METHOD <str>] [-EPSILON <double>] [-LEVEL_MAX <num>] [-UPDATE <str>] [-DATATYPE <str>]
-GRID:<str> Grid
Grid (input)
-TARGET_DEFINITION:<str> Target Grid System
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] user defined
[1] grid or grid system
Default: 0
-TARGET_USER_SIZE:<double> Cellsize
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
Default: 1.000000
-TARGET_USER_XMIN:<double> Left
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-TARGET_USER_XMAX:<double> Right
Floating point
Default: 100.000000
-TARGET_USER_YMIN:<double> Bottom
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-TARGET_USER_YMAX:<double> Top
Floating point
Default: 100.000000
-TARGET_USER_FITS:<str> Fit
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] nodes
[1] cells
Default: 0
-TARGET_TEMPLATE:<str> Target System
Grid (optional input)
-TARGET_OUT_GRID:<str> Target Grid
Grid (output)
-METHOD:<str> Method
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] without B-spline refinement
[1] with B-spline refinement
Default: 1
-EPSILON:<double> Threshold Error
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
Default: 0.000100
-LEVEL_MAX:<num> Maximum Level
Integer
Minimum: 1
Maximum: 14
Default: 11
-UPDATE:<str> Update View
Boolean
Default: 0
-DATATYPE:<str> Data Type
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] same as input grid
[1] floating point
Default: 1
Execution completed in 2.38 seconds
Results:
{'TARGET_OUT_GRID': '/Users/PassifloraTsui/Desktop/study_area/ssTemp_BSpline.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/Users/PassifloraTsui/Desktop/study_area/ssTemp_BSpline.sdat</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

and I've checked the documentation of this algorithm in SAGA website, which said the LEVEL_MAX should be an integer, not a float number, however, QGIS automatically converts it to a float number, which leads to the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm - that's a bug in QGIS. Fixed for QGIS 3.4 here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/8344.

In the meantime, look for the `MultilevelB-SplineInterpolation(fromGrid).txt` file from your QGIS install folder, and change the line

```
QgsProcessingParameterNumber|LEVEL_MAX|Maximum Level|QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double|11.0|False|1|14
```

to

```
QgsProcessingParameterNumber|LEVEL_MAX|Maximum Level|QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer|11|False|1|14
```

Save and reload QGIS.

Comment: OK, I've found the location of this file: /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/description/MultilevelB-SplineInterpolation(fromGrid).txt Many thanks for your answer!